# Codegen error using Micornaut and swagger

Tags: java, swagger, micronaut, swagger-codegen

I am new to micronaut framework.
I am trying to generate code using codegen from [franz-see](https://github.com/franz-see/swagger-codegen-micronaut-generator)

But getting error.
I downloaded both the jars in the same directory and running the java -cp command from the command line.

The command I used:

```
java -cp swagger-codegen-micronaut-generator-1.0.1.jar:swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.10.jar \
  io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen \
  generate \
  -l ph.net.see.swaggercodegenmicronautgenerator.MicronautCodegen \
  -i /Users/abc/Downloads/demo/src/main/resources/api-spec/Provider.yaml \
  -o /Users/abc/micronaut_projects
```

The error I am getting is below. Basically, it's a Runtime exception, seems like the class is missing from this version. Although I found this from the official page from the above URL:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load config class with name ph.net.see.swaggercodegenmicronautgenerator.MicronautCodegen Available: aspnetcore
csharp
csharp-dotnet2
dynamic-html
html
html2
java
jaxrs-cxf-client
jaxrs-cxf
inflector
jaxrs-cxf-cdi
jaxrs-spec
jaxrs-jersey
jaxrs-di
jaxrs-resteasy-eap
jaxrs-resteasy
spring
nodejs-server
openapi
openapi-yaml
kotlin-client
kotlin-server
php
python
python-flask
scala
scala-akka-http-server
swift3
swift4
typescript-angular

    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:31)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ph.net.see.swaggercodegenmicronautgenerator.MicronautCodegen
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:29)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Thats a classpath issue. Make sure the two jar your are setting to the classpath `swagger-codegen-micronaut-generator-1.0.1.jar:swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.10.jar` are in the same directory where you start the `java` process from terminal.

If that does not work I recommend to create an issue so the author of this codegen can have a look at it https://github.com/franz-see/swagger-codegen-micronaut-generator/issues

Comment: @saw303 : Yes they both are in the same directory